# Error sharing a pnpm workspace package using nuxt layer

Tags: nuxt.js, monorepo, pnpm

Nuxt layer provides the functionality to share the dependencies in the apps which extend the layer.

In my setup, I have a pnpm monorepo in which there is a:

- a base nuxt layer
- a nuxt app app1 extending base layer
- base layer is using 2 dependency packages

  - supervillains
  - good(local pnpm workspace package)

Issue: I am able to use supervillains in app1 but not local package (pnpm workspace)

Error screenshot
[image]

Repository for reproduction https://github.com/yugal-compro/nuxt-monorepo

Appreciate the help to fix it or any workarounds